# How to list all the created queue and topic in azure service bus

Tags: azure

I have created 4 different queues and 1 topic in azure. 
I want to display these queues and topics on a page. 
Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by displaying? Properties, message count, or something else? What's the purpose of that "page"?

Comment: I just want to get the names of the queues and topics... Or I could say like I want to print on the console the available queue names..  I just have the connection string!  I hope this would help you

Answer (score 2):

To list all of your entities, you should look into [`NamespaceManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0) class. It can list all of the entities by their type ([`Get​Queues​Async()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.getqueuesasync?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_NamespaceManager_GetQueuesAsync) and [`Get​Topics​Async()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.gettopicsasync?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_NamespaceManager_GetTopicsAsync)).

There are overloads to take filters, but that filtering is poorly documented and somewhat broken.